# Video Background con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

He estado haciendo un background mediante JS que cambia segun la hora del dia, y tengo una duda.
El background Funciona así:
- Tengo un video que corre a partir de las 7 am (ejemplo: 07:00:00) y cuando llegue la noche (19:10:12) necesito que se cambie el video background.
- Funciona el reloj, pero no cambia el vídeo cuando llega la hora establecida.

**Pueden revisar el código aquí.**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqOEBr

Comment: A que te refieres con que funciona bien? si dices que no cambia el video?

Comment: Creo que no evalua bien el if. Ten en cuenta que evalua la hora como una cadena. Obten la hora en milisegundos y comparala con la hora que quieras tambien en milisegundos

Comment: @acensito algún ejemplo

Comment: Te sugiero modifiques tu pregunta en base a [ask], saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys editado

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no evalua bien el if. Ten en cuenta que evalua la hora como una cadena. Obten la hora en milisegundos y comparala con la hora que quieras tambien en milisegundos.

Te dejo una revisión del código tuyo que funciona parcialmente. Evalua las dos fechas, pero no hace el cambio salvo que se cargue de nuevo la pagina.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReRoVY